# How to remove duplicate fields in an XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <queryResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <records xsi:type="sObject">
   <type>Task</type>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>1xyz</name>
   <lastname>1abc </lastname>
   <id>1</id>
   </records>
   <records xsi:type="sObject">
   <type>Task</type>
   <id>2</id>
   <name>2xyz</name>
   <lastname>2abc </lastname>
   <id>2</id>
   </records>
   </queryResult>
```

I want to remove second id tag in the same record field. So my desired xml is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <queryResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <records xsi:type="sObject">
   <type>Task</type>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>1xyz</name>
   <lastname>1abc </lastname>
   </records>
   <records xsi:type="sObject">
   <type>Task</type>
   <id>2</id>
   <name>2xyz</name>
   <lastname>2abc </lastname>
  </records>
 </queryResult>
```

So basically I want to remove that extra id tag from my xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't specify the XSLT version, I used version 2.0.

Note that your source XML uses the **default namespace** of
*http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload*, so generally you should
mention it in `stylesheet` XSLT element.

But to simplify the script, you can specify it as `xpath-default-namespace`,
so you do not need to specify it as a "regular" namespace.

The idea to write the script is simple: write a template matching `records`
(in the default namespace, as specified before). This template shoud:

- Copy the source opening tag.
- Apply templates to the **first** `id` child element.
- Apply templates to all child elements, except `id`.
- Copy the source closing tag.

Your script should include also the *identity template*.

So the whole script can be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="records">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="id[1]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* except id"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5wD

### Edit

Another solution is to write an **empty template** matching `id`,
which has `preceding-sibling` element with name `id`:

```
<xsl:template match="id[preceding-sibling::id]"/>
```

So the whole script can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="id[preceding-sibling::id]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The difference is that this time you keep the order of child elements,
whereas the first solution "moves" the `id` element to the beginning.

Note: This time I added `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to avoid empty
lines in the output.

Comment: Hii @valdi_bo , I am sorry but I am completely unknown about xml and xslt. I just want to get rid of this extra tag instantly. Can you help me with the script directly. As I see in your answer there are steps which I need to follow. But I need one code to resolve my problem. Please provide easiest way to resolve this error. If you need detailed content of the file tell me I'll provide you.

Comment: I have just provided the **complete** XSLT script, even in 2 versions, not steps to solve the problem.